# Passing a value through to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, parameter-passing

when I try to pass this value, I get this error

> 09 is not a legal ECMA-262 octal constant [Break On This Error]
>
> linkClicked(SS-10-04-2012-0199)
>
> javasc...2-0199) (line 1, col 26)      SS is not defined

Not sure what it means, tried converting the value to string beforehand etc but then it won't read at all

```
for(var i=0; i < resultArray.length; i++){
var temp = resultArray[i].pp_order_details_id;
$('#results').append('<tr><td><a href="javascript:linkClicked(' + temp + ')">' + resultArray[i].pp_order_details_id + '</a></td><td>' + resultArray[i].order_ref + '</td><td>' + resultArray[i].status + '</td></tr>');
}
```

Above is where the data is written to the table
The user should click the link, and the pp_order_details_id should be passed to the linkClicked function below

```
function linkClicked(orderno) {
$.post("../../order/get-order.php", {
    orderRef: orderno
}, function (data) {
    if (data.match("set")) { $('#my_order_details').fadeOut("fast").load('index#my_order_details').fadeIn("fast");
    }
});
}
```

I'm probably doing the passing thing wrong because I'm not used to it, but thought I'd ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of the error message this is your call to `linkClicked`:

```
linkClicked(SS-10-04-2012-0199)
```

But you need to pass a string. Notice the addition of the escaped `'` characters:

```
$('#results').append('<tr><td><a href="javascript:linkClicked(\'' + temp + '\')">' //...
```

This should result in the call looking like this:

```
linkClicked('SS-10-04-2012-0199')
```

Comment: fantastic! don't understand why the first backslash is before the first apostrophe, but it worked great!

Comment: @Pam - It's there because the second apostrophe is the one that ends the string literal being passed to append. The first apostrophe is part of that string literal, if that makes sense. In any case, glad I could help :)

Comment: Yeah, I stared at it a bit after and I understood what was happening :) Thanks for that!